# Application.LoadLevel() on Google Cardboard starting upside down

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

When restarting my Google Cardboard game with Application.LoadLevel(0); my Google Cardboard game starts upsidedown my my phone (fine in the editor but with error), and no input works on it (such as tap or pulling of the trigger).

When calling Application.LoadLevel(0); in the error it loads fine but gives this error:

> Some objects were not cleaned up when closing the scene. (Did you spawn new Game Objects from OnDestroy?)

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code that's responsible for broken features (orientation of the camera and input)?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in 0.4.10 when using Unity 4 Free that causes this.  You can turn off the Native Distortion Correction option in the Inspector panel for CardboardMain.  Alternatively, the bug is not there in 0.4.9, so you could use that version.

Comment: I also tried the latest SDK version and it was right side up.